# Returning 404 on python script https problems?

Tags: python, firebase

I have most of this app running smoothly I am trying to get this python code to send serial data through but I always get a 404 when I try to use python3 I get issues with the serialutil as far as basestring not being defined etc etc in the serial libraries. So I revert back to python 2.7 and am wondering if its possible to add the https into the string somewhere just to override whatever is happening that is reverting it back to http?

```py
import serial
import time
import requests
import json

firebase_url = 'https://ourfleet.firebaseio.com'
auth_token = '0sBNZjz4uQvLteDoGSAJSKSDKSDBNASASJSDL'

#Connect to Serial Port for communication
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/tty.wchusbserial410', 9600, timeout=0)

#Setup a loop to send GPS values at fixed intervals
#in seconds
fixed_interval = 10

while 1:
    try:
        #GPS value obtained from Arduino + Ublox
        gps_c = ser.readline()
        #current time and date
        time_hhmmss = time.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
        date_mmddyyyy = time.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')

        #current location name
        gps_location = 'ourfleet'

        print (gps_c + ',' + time_hhmmss + ',' + date_mmddyyyy + ',' + gps_location)

        #insert record

        data = {'date':date_mmddyyyy,'time':time_hhmmss,'location':gps_c}

        result = requests.post('https://ourfleet.firebaseio.com' + '/' + gps_location + '/gps_c.json'+ auth_token, data=json.dumps(data))

        #insert record
        print ('Record inserted. Result Code = ' + str(result.status_code) + ',' + result.text)
        time.sleep(fixed_interval)
    except IOError:
        print('Error! Something went wrong.')
        time.sleep(fixed_interval)
```

Comment: You aren't correctly appending your auth token. As presented, your URL would resemble: `https://..../gps_c.json0sBNZ...` when you want it to have ?auth= in that URL. Additionally, that looks like your Firebase secret, which will allow anyone full admin access to your data. You should revoke that immediately and never post it again.

Comment: This isnt my real firebase secret I edited it out. Thanks I will try adding ?auth= before the token.